# How to use Cauchy integral to evaluate the integral $\int_C \frac{\cos\ z}{z(z^2+8)}dz$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The integral in question is:

> $$\large{\int_C \frac{\cos\ z}{z(z^2+8)}dz}$$
>   Where $C$ is the square whose vertices are $x=\pm2, y=\pm2$, anti-clockwise direction.

I did the natural thing to split them up using partial fraction decomposition, but I am stuck immediately. Any help/insights is deeply appreciated.

Comment: That should be a straight forward implementation of the Cauchy integral formula. What is your point of confusion ?

Comment: After you split them up, I have a term $\int \frac{zcos\ z}{8(z^2+8)}dz$, how do I evaluate this term ?

Comment: No you should decompose around each singularity mainly you can use 

$$(z^2+8) = (z- i 2\sqrt{2}) (z+ i 2\sqrt{2})$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{1}{z(z^2+8)}=\frac{1/8}{z}-\frac{z/8}{z^2+8}=\frac{1/8}{z}-\frac{1/16}{z+i2\sqrt 2}-\frac{1/16}{z-i2\sqrt 2}$$

Note that the only pole enclosed by the square contour is the one at $z=0$.